# ReactJS - List, Detail, New, Edit Pages - When to load data form API with Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have multiple functional collections in my app, each of them has a list page that includes a table listing all of them, a detail page clicking on one of the table entries, an edit page and a page for creating a new one.

The state of the collections is managed with Redux and fetched from a backend. What is the common pattern to fetch the data from the backend in this scenario?

- Should it be fetched only by the list page à la `fetchAllObjects` and then be passed when moving to a new page (like props.history.push + state) and passed again by moving back (e.g. when editing, saving and returning to the detail page so that the updated data is displayed)
- or should each sub page fetch the data again to have the most up-to-date vesion? Meaning to fetch all objects in the list page, but also to do `fetchOneObject` in the detail and edit page so I don't need to pass around state with the history.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both the things with the redux. But think about the case which would be more optimised. Think the number of calls you have to make to backend.

In the first case, you can make one call when componentDidMount, then when you move around pages, you can simply use that data. Even if you make any updations, you can do that on your redux store also. So that you maintain your local redux store and backend store in sync and no need of any further calls.

But think about the second case, if you are calling backend everytime, then there is no use of using redux.

And finally one suggestion, don't pass props when you use redux, you can simply connect that component to redux. Props passing is easy but it would become more hectic when you have a traffic of props.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to do `fetchAllObjects` on the list page, then pass the specific detail on detail page as params or state if you're using react-router-dom or as props, so you don't have stale data.

The flow is:

1. Fetch list of data - after component mounted, makes sure fresh data are seen
2. Get specific detail and pass to edit/update page
3. Request update to api.

Whenever the list page component is mounted it requests for the lists of data. Or you can use redux-saga to listen for update actions and fetch your lists of data and update the store.